# Detecting whether strings arise in a specific order

Tags: r, string, count, stringr, detect

I'd like to count the number of times my students could state 5 specific words AND subset/filter for the students' responses in which the words were in the correct order.
The correct order= green, yellow, orange, red, black.
All the data is in lower case and has no punctuation:

```
#     Student responses
Id    Data$Colors
1     green yellow orange red black
2     yellow green orange red black
3     red violet pink black
4     purple green orange red black
5     blue pink yellow scarlet
```

The output I'm aiming for is:

```
#   Student responses
Id  Data$Colors                                Data$Count   Data$CorrOrder
1   green yellow orange red black              5            TRUE
2   yellow green orange red blacks             4            FALSE
3   red violet pink black                      2            TRUE
4   purple green orange red black              4            TRUE
5   blue pink yellow brown                     1            NA
6   green yellow orange red very red black     4*           TRUE
```

-1 point for repetition.
I've been able to get the count column by doing this

```
Data <- c("\\bgreen\\b", "\\byellow\\b", "\\borange\\b", "\\bred\\b", "\\bblack\\b")

Data$Count<- str_count(Data$Colors, paste(Data, collapse = '|'))
```

However, this doesn't subtract for repeated correct colors like Id 6.

Anyone know how I could generate `Data$CorrOrder`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a start, if you treat the values as an `ordered` factor, you can check if they are sorted, without sorting, using `is.unsorted`:

```
colorder <- c("green", "yellow", "orange", "red", "black")

spl <- lapply(strsplit(dat$Colors, "\\s+"), ordered, levels=colorder)
cnt <- sapply(spl, function(x) length(unique(na.omit(x))) - sum(tabulate(x) > 1) )
cnt
#[1] 5 4 2 4 1 4
out <- !sapply(spl, is.unsorted, na.rm=TRUE)
out[cnt == 1] <- NA
out
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE    NA  TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `tidyverse` we can get `Count` and `CorrOrder` separately. To get `Count` we first split `Colors` on space and create `separate_rows` for each color so that it is easy to compare values. We then count how many of `unique` `Colors` are present in each `Id` out of the total `all_colors` and since we want to give -1 for each repeated value we subtract it by number of `duplicated` value in each group giving us the total score.

```
all_colors <- c("green", "yellow", "orange", "red", "black")
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df %>%
      left_join(df %>%
                 separate_rows(Colors, sep = "\\s+") %>%
                 group_by(Id) %>%
                 summarise(count = max(sum(all_colors %in% unique(Colors)) - 
                                   sum(duplicated(Colors)), 0)))
```

To get correct order we again separate colors into different rows keep only the colors from `all_colors` and remove duplicates and check if the order in which the color appears are always increasing and assign logical `TRUE`/`FALSE` value accordingly.

```
df1 %>%
   left_join(df1 %>%
              separate_rows(Colors, sep = "\\s+") %>%
              group_by(Id) %>%
              filter(Colors %in% all_colors & !duplicated(Colors)) %>%
              summarise(new = if (n() == 1) NA 
              else all(diff(na.omit(match(Colors, all_colors))) > 0)))

#  Id                                 Colors CorOrder Count
#1  1          green yellow orange red black     TRUE     5
#2  2         yellow green orange red blacks    FALSE     4
#3  3                  red violet pink black     TRUE     2
#4  4          purple green orange red black     TRUE     4
#5  5                 blue pink yellow brown       NA     1
#6  6 green yellow orange red very red black     TRUE     4
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak, this is very helpful. I have a couple of follow up questions. With the first section you provided, do you know how I make sure the -1s given for repeated colors stops at 0? (Some of the rows are ending up with negative scores which I don't want). And with the second section I'm getting the following message: "Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, DRRecallCorrOrder, value = c(TRUE, : replacement has 3065 rows, data has 3172". Any ideas why?

Comment: @interestedfinnfisher For the first issue we can use `max` to make sure the value stops at 0. I have updated that part of the answer. Regarding your second question I was not able to reproduce it so I am guessing that do you have `NA` or some empty value in `Colors` column?

Comment: Hi Ronak, thanks very much for the suggestion of using max(), that works now. However I don't have any empty rows/NAs in the Colors column and I still can't fix this problem of having a mismatch in the number of rows between the intended output and the input dataframe

Comment: @interestedfinnfisher Can you try the updated version? I have included `na.omit` in the answer after `match`.

Comment: Could you solve possible mismatches here by not using `pull` and instead joining the summaries to the original data based on ID?

Comment: @RonakShah, your first example produces a count column which works, and doesn't count duplicates, however, your second example, the CorOrder column isn't being produced in df1. It's just printing the whole of the df1 table